# Why is only the first mouse-over and mouse-out working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

I have loaded a set of images and applied `.mouseout()` and `.mouseover()` on them.  The problem is that after the first `.mouseover()` event the image gets larger and after `.mouseout()` is fired the image is returned back to its previous size.  After the first time, no `.mouseover()` event gets fired in Firefox, but in Chrome it works. The problem is that the Chrome `z-index` property does not put the `mouseover` image on top of other images. What is the reason for these problems and how can I solve them?

```js
var images = ['http://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/04/01-cat-wants-to-tell-you-laptop.jpg', 'http://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/cx_462/cy_245/cw_1349/ch_1349/w_720/APL/uploads/2015/06/caturday-shutterstock_149320799.jpg', 'http://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/cx_462/cy_245/cw_1349/ch_1349/w_720/APL/uploads/2015/06/caturday-shutterstock_149320799.jpg', 'http://pershanpet.ir/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/144-jpravafcbn.jpg', 'http://www.animal-whisper.com/images/pic28.jpg'];

function loadImage(url) {
  var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
      resolve(image);
    };
    image.onerror = function() {
      var msg = "could not load image at url " + url;
      reject(new Error(msg));
    };
    image.src = url;
    image.style.width = '200px';
    image.style.height = '200px';

  });
  return promise;
}

Promise.all(
  images.map(function(elem) {
    return loadImage(elem);
  })
).then((img) => {
  img.forEach(each => {

    each.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {

      this.style.zIndex = '2000';
      this.style.transform = 'scale(1.5,1.5)';

    });
    each.addEventListener('mouseout', function(event) {

      this.style.transform = 'scale(1,1)';
      this.style.zIndex = '-1';
    });
    addImg(each);
  });
});

function addImg(img) {
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to set up a demonstration of the issue? In a jsfiddle or something?

Comment: fiddle is added

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your images get under some other elements with `z-index` that is greater than `-1`. On `mouseout` try `this.style.zIndex = '0'`.

Comment: ok setting z index solved for firefox but not for chrome.why is it behaving differently in chrome

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're setting the image's `z-index` to `-1`. Any reason for that?

Try setting `this.style.zIndex = '1';` on mouseout.